# How do you test hooks with no trigger event like a click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Seems to be a lot on how to run a test for hooks as long as there is some type of onClick, onChange, etc etc but what if you are passing that function down to your event handling component like I am below?

```
const Content: FC<Props> = ({ activeTab }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

  function handleDateUpdate(dates: object) {
    const totalCount = new GetTotal(dates, activeTab);
    setCount(totalCount.totalAttendances());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeTab === 'Year') {
      handleDateUpdate(new Date());
    }
  });

  return (
    <Container>
        {activeTab === 'Month' && (
          <Datepicker handleDateUpdate={handleDateUpdate} />
        )}
      <TotalAttendences count={count} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I would like to write a test that checks the if statement in the useEffect as well as the handleDateUpdate to ensure that it is doing what I intend it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether `handleDateUpdate` has been called, I recommend extracting it to a helper file and then exporting it with `export function`. Then, you import the entire helper file into the file where you define the component by doing the following:
`import * as dateHelpers from '../path/to/file';`

So that when you call the function in the component, you do so as `dateHelpers.handleDateUpdate`. This will ensure that the dependency is correctly injected so that you will be able to spy on the instance of the `handleDateUpdate` function that you invoke in your component to ensure that it is properly called (or not).

Since `activeTab` is the prop of `<Content />`, I would test the `useEffect` by doing the following:

```
import { shallow } from enzyme;
// I'm using enzyme here, but you could use whatever React testing library you choose
import * as dateHelpers from '../path/to/file/'

describe('<Content />', () => {
  let dateUpdateSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    dateUpdateSpy = jest.spyOn(dateHelpers, 'handleDateUpdate'); 
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  it('should invoke handleDateUpdate() when the activeTab prop equals "Year"'), () 
  => {
    shallow(<Content activeTab="Year" />);

    expect(dateUpdateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Date());
  }


  it('should not invoke handleDateUpdate() when the activeTab prop does not equal 
  "Year"'), () => {
    shallow(<Content activeTab="Month" />);

    expect(dateUpdateSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
}
```

Last thing, you should add `activeTab` as the dependency to the `useEffect` since you only want to run that callback function if `activeTab` changes. It will run on mount but if there is a rerender for any reason other than `activeTab` changing, you will needlessly rerun `useEffect`. So I would change that to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (activeTab === 'Year') {
    dateHelpers.handleDateUpdate(new Date());
  }
}, [activeTab]);
``
```

Comment: Cheers, Is there not a way to keep it all in one file?

Comment: Here's a thought: You could leave the function where it is and test to see that `setCount` was called by mocking useState.

`const mockSetState = jest.fn();`
 `jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(init => [init, mockSetState]);`

And then your assertion checks to see if `mockSetState` was called (or not) based on which prop you pass to `<Content />` in your test.